# Print NFC tag data in a listview on xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

So I have a project with my group we are trying to print data info from a NFC tag, we have done the part of reading the data but can't seem to find a way of printing it once read to a listview on another class that will receive all the data.

*We reused some NFC code.

```
                string cedula = data.Replace("en", string.Empty);
                string estudiante = data2.Replace("en", string.Empty);

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            var shb = new SoapHexBinary(ba);
            return shb.ToString();
        }

        JObject o = new JObject();

        public void GuardarDatosJson(String nombre, String cedula)
        {

            JArray array = new JArray();
            array.Add(nombre);
            array.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            
            o[cedula + DateTime.Now.Ticks] = array;

            EstudianteData.listado = o.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your ListView?  What is its ItemsSource?  Why are you using JObject and JArray?  You would generally create a C# class to model your data and then use a List or ObservableCollection of that model to store your data and act as an ItemsSource for your ListView.  It’s not at all clear what the code you posted is supposed to do.

Comment: Your sample code is incomplete with regards to the question. Where are you creating the ListView and how are you assigning elements to it? What have you tried and where do you suspect it may be going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more code for Listview and ItemsSource?